# MFC how to change the background color of a disabled CEdit

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to change the background color of a `CEdit` which is set to `disabled`.
I tried to change it in `OnCtlColor`. But the `CEdit` is still a gray background:

```cpp
m_hEditBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));

...

if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)
    {
        CString ss;
        pWnd->GetWindowText(ss);
        switch(pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID())
        {
        case IDC_EDIT_USERNAME:
        {
            pDC->SetBkColor(EDIT_BK_COLOR);
            return m_hEditBrush;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the disabled edit control, you need to respond to `CTLCOLOR_STATIC`:

```
if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
{
    switch (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID())
    {
    case IDC_EDIT_USERNAME:
    {
        pDC->SetBkColor(EDIT_BK_COLOR));
        return m_hEditBrush;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```